# why is scanner not working

Tags: java

I am trying to read a input of this format

```
4 4
* . . .
. . . .
. * . .
. . . .
4 4
* * . .
. . . .
. . . .
. . * .
```

I am able to read the first two numbers, when I try to read the symbols I get an exception. I can use BufferedReader to read each line and parse the input but why can't I do this with scanner?

This is my code

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(in.nextLine());
                    if (!s.hasNextLine())
                        break;

                    int x = s.nextInt(); // 4
                    int y = s.nextInt(); // 4
                    for (int i = 0; i <= x - 1; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j <= y - 1; j++) {
                            System.out.println(s.hasNext()); // false
                            String symbol = s.next(); //NoSuchElementException WHY?
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't try to read numbers when there aren't any numbers there.

Your loop, in pseudocode, looks like

```
While there is a line available:
    s = NextLine()
    x = FirstInt(s)
    y = SecondInt(s)
    // Some other stuff
```

When you assign to `x` and `y`, there is no number available except on the first line, so your application crashes.

A better solution, which matches the problem, would be

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
if (!in.hasNextInt()) exitAndPrintError();
int rows = in.nextInt();
if (!in.hasNextInt()) exitAndPrintError();
int cols = in.nextInt();
for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
        if (!in.hasNext()) exitAndPrintError();
        process(in.next());
    }
}
```

This solution really doesn't check much for errors, leaving all error reporting to some `exitAndPrintError` function that you would have to write.

As a side note: if you try `s.hasNext()` and it returns false, then you should be surprised if `s.next()` *does not* throw an exception.  That's why the `hasNext*` methods are available on `Scanner` - they give you the chance to know when you have reached the end of the input, and not try to read any more input than is available.

---

I'll leave it as an exercise to update this code to handle multiple sets of data in a single file, but it isn't that difficult.  The key bug in the code you posted is that, if you create a scanner `s` using only a line from `in`, you won't find a multi-line structure inside that single line that `s` is processing.

Comment: Take a look at the updated Input.But I am trying to get the symbol inside the for loop using Next the code breaks at the location

Comment: Thanks it seems I used two scanners so that I can exit out of the loop and that messed things up. I will use only one scanner

Answer (score 1):

Overall design problems withstanding, I will answer your question.

You get the `NoSuchElementException` because, guess what, `s` has no more elements. It becomes even more obvious with the output of `s.hasNext()` which returns false.

The reason is simple. You assign `s` with a single line of `in`.

To fix the whole program, all you need to use is one scanner, and not multiple instances of it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Btw I used two scanners so that I can break the loop. Say if I had only one scanner I would do while(in.hasNext) and get the values but I cant break it without a termination string provided by the user

Comment: @YeshwanthVenkatesh No, that's not true.  It is absolutely possible to solve this problem with a single scanner, looking only for EOF as the termination condition.

Comment: @YeshwanthVenkatesh You can manage that with a cleverly placed conditional `continue`.